# Prepend variable to top of CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV that shows IP Addresses, Hostnames, and OS_Names.  I am looking to get a count of each OS type and prepend it to the top of the CSV.  I can successfully get the count of the OS references, I'm just stuck on prepend it to top of the CSV. Ultimately I would like to get $c1 and $c2 prepend to the top of the CSV.

```
$a1 = get-content 'test.csv' |select-string "Server 2008"
$b1 = $a1.count
$c1 = 'WIN2k8:' + $b1

$a2 = get-content 'test.csv' |select-string "Server 2003"
$b2 = $a2.count
$c2 = 'WIN2k3:' + $b2
```

Comment: `$c1,$c2,(get-content 'test.csv') | Set-Content c:\temp\newfile.txt` or something close. Where 'test.csv' is the whole file and c1,c2 is what you want in the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works a little cleaner than what I had in the comments

```powershell
$file = Get-Content C:\temp\web40repallServersMaster.csv
$c1 = 'WIN2k8: ' + ($file  |select-string "Server 2008").Count
$c2 = 'WIN2k8: ' + ($file  |select-string "Server 2003").Count
$c1,$c2,$file | Set-Content C:\temp\web40repallServersMaster.csv
```

Capture the file in the array `$file`. Then we run your counts and capture the results in the variables `$c1` and `$c2`. Build another array of those items and the original file which we pipe to `Set-Content`.

**Grammar**

Mine's terrible. Thanks Nathan.